# xgettext with a custom input format

Tags: internationalization, xgettext

xgettext is capable of extracting strings for translation from a variety of source languages.

```
   -L, --language=NAME
          recognise  the  specified  language (C, C++, ObjectiveC, PO,
          Shell, Python, Lisp, EmacsLisp, librep, Scheme, Smalltalk,
          Java, JavaProperties, C#, awk, YCP, Tcl, Perl, PHP, GCC-source,
          NXStringTable, RST, Glade, Lua, JavaScript, Vala, Desktop)
```

(your exact list may vary by platform)

It also guesses the type based on the file extension, so:

```
$ xgettext -o out.pot in.php
```

will use the PHP parser without needing `-L PHP`.

However, I wish to translate files that aren't in any of those languages. Is it possible to submit a list of strings into xgettext directly? Or to teach it a new language?

For example, consider some Handlebars templates using a custom helper function `__`, like so:

```
<title>{{__ 'My Website'}}</title>
```

It's possible to extract all the strings from the files using grep:

```
$ grep '\{\{__ (.+?)\}\}' -Ero views
views/index.hbs:{{__ 'My Website'}}
```

But is there any way of feeding this information into xgettext to produce a valid pot file?

Note: while I'd appreciate a solution to this specific case, the question is really about the general case of an unknown language.

Comment: I think the short answer about teaching it a new language, is you can't. 
However, I can parse your example using `xgettext -L JavaScript --extract-all`

Comment: That doesn't work particularly well, because `--extract-all` extracts ALL the quoted strings in the file. For example, for the source

`<li><a rel='#howto-tab' class='selected'>{{__ "How to"}}</a></li>`

it extracts the strings `"#howto-tab"`, `"selected"` and `"How to"`. Without that option, all it produces is errors.

Comment: For the time being I have a messy scripted solution that produces tolerably compatible pot files.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution for this? This is exactly the need I have

Comment: @tobiak777 Not using xgettext, I'm afraid. I wrote my own code that parses my specific file format and produces POT files.